# When I break demon alters I don't get mythril in terraria

Tags: terraria

I have been trying to get mythril but it comes up with all the other ores instead of mythril.im.

I'm not sure if I need to be in a specific biome for different demon alters to get mythril.oh I defeated the WoF.

I got the hammer and I don't know witch if I need a specific hammer, I defeated the WoF 2 times and it only gave me the Agile Pwnhammer and the Keen Pwnhammer.

And I also got mythril on my iPad but i just can't get it on my pc.

help would be much appreciated! :)

Comment: Have you broken the second demon altar? Also, you might not get Mythril, but Orichalcum instead (it's randomly decided when breaking the altar). Source: [Altar, on official wiki](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Demon_Altar)

Comment: ooooohhhhh hat helps i have 11 of that stuff thanks :) and is mythril pretty much the same as Orchalcum?

Comment: Orichalcum is slightly better than Mythril, but give different effect for respective armor though.

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 tiers of hardmode ores in Terraria, each tier containing two ores. They are:

- [Cobalt](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Cobalt_Ore) and [Palladium](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Palladium_Ore)
- [Mythril](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Mythril_Ore) and [Orichalcum](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Orichalcum_Ore)
- [Adamantite](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Adamantite_Ore) and [Titanium](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Titanium_Ore)

The game randomly picks one from each tier to be unlocked when destroying demon altars. After destroying three of them, you will ALWAYS have deposits of cobalt or palladium, mythril or orichalcum, and adamantite or titanium.

Chances are that the world you're in generated orichalcum instead of mythril. It's not a bad thing, it just means that your anvil is going to be pink instead of green, and the armors/weapons tied to that ore have slightly different properties. Orichalcum is *slightly* better than mythril in terms of armor value and damage, but not by much.

Comment: You'll need to start a new world and defeat the WoF again. Then destroy more altars in that new world and see if they generated Mythril there.